# How to prove the axioms of equivalence relation without using example but theoretically or using logic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, logic, equivalence-relations, axioms

As we know , if $\sim$ is an Equivalence relation on a set $A$ then $\forall a, b, c\in A$ we have

i) $a\sim a$ (Reflexive)

ii) if $a\sim b$ then $b\sim a$ (symmetric)

iii) if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ then $a\sim c$ (transitive)

My question is we take these axioms of equivalence relation as granted and somehow try to prove it by taking example, but how can we prove these axioms of equivalence relation theoretically or by using logic?

And also why there is "if.. then" condition is used in symmetry and transitive property why not "if and only if" condition can't be use?

Comment: You can’t prove axioms (in this context). You can prove that, if I gave you some relation, the relation is or isn’t an equivalence. The fundamental axioms themselves can’t be proven since they’re just a definition

Comment: @FShrike if axiom can't be proven then how can we be sure that these axioms are right or wrong?

Comment: "we take these axioms of equivalence relation as granted" YES, because **they are** the definition of *equivalence relation*.

Comment: They’re not right or wrong. I can tell you that they’re reasonable and useful, but formally they just are what they are - a definition

Comment: @FShrike On what basis you can say that these axioms are reasonable and useful?

Comment: "why there is "if.. then" condition used..." A definition is an "iff" statement, meaning that we have "Relation ∼ is Reflexive **iff** a∼a". But for Symmetry we have "Relation ∼ is Symmetric **iff** (if a∼b then b∼a)".

Comment: We say the phrase "equivalence relation" to refer to any relation that satisfies this axioms. It makes no sense whatsoever to say that these axioms are right or wrong. This is just a definition of a term that we use in our language.

Comment: These are definitions, not theorems. So you don't prove them. I can *define* a bachelor to be an adult unmarried male, but I cannot *prove* a bachelor to be an adult unmarried male.

Comment: @Bram28 so i can establish any abstract arbitrary definition since there is no way to prove definition, is that what you are saying?

Comment: @SabinaShrestha Exactly!! We can define things any which way we want. I can define a 'knurb' to be a number divisible by 17. It doesn;t make sense to ask me to prove that ... indeed, to prove anything about 'knurbs' you would need to first know what a 'knurb' is ... and that's exactly what a definition does. Same here: we are merely defining what an 'equivalence relation' is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing definitions with theorems.

I can define a 'knurb' to be a number divisible by 17. But it doesn't make sense to ask me to prove that as if it were a theorem... indeed, to prove anything about 'knurbs' you would need to first know what a 'knurb' is ... and that's exactly what a definition does.

Same with your post: we are merely defining what an 'equivalence relation' is

As far as your second question goes:

> And also why there is "if.. then" condition is used in symmetry and transitive property why not "if and only if" condition can't be use?

I am wondering if maybe you are asking your question because you might have seen 'if and only if' being used in the context of these definitions, where they indeed regularly occur. Indeed, we can say:

$\sim$ is symmetric **if and only if** for any $a$ and  $b$: if $ a \sim b $ then $ b \sim a$

But notice that the use of the 'if and only if' is used to define 'symmetry', and the 'if ... then ...' in the second half is a claim about the $\sim$ relationship. So these are two different things.

Now, it turns out that I *can* define symmetry as follows:

$\sim$ is symmetric if and only if for any $a$ and $b$: $a \sim b$ if and only if $b \sim a$

But it is, in a way, just happenstance that we can use an 'if and only if' in the second half here. That is, it just so happens to be true (i.e. this is a *theorem*) that:

for any $a$ and  $b$: if $ a \sim b $ then $ b \sim a$ **if and only if** for any $a$ and  $b$: $ a \sim b $ if and only if $ b \sim a$

On the other hand, if you say that :

$\sim$ is transitive **if and only if** for any $a$, $b$, and $c$: $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$ if and only if $a \sim c$

then you have really changed the meaning of 'transitive'. For example, if $a,b,c$ are numbers, then we have that if $a < b$ and $b < c$, then $a < c$. That makes sense right? But it is clearly not true that $a < b$ and $b < c$ if and only if $a < c$: if we pick $a = 1$, $b = 3$, and $c = 2$, then we have $a < c$, but we don't have that $a < b$ and $b < c$!

Finally, let's bring this back full circle. Please note that we can *define* whatever we want and however we want! So, we *could* have defined 'transitivity' in the above manner. But note that would have meant that $<$ is not 'transitive'. Indeed, many interesting things would not be 'transitive' under that definition of transitive.  ... in other words, 'transitive' would not point out a very interesting property. But with the original definition of transitivity we can point out that $<$ is transitive ... and indeed it expresses an interesting property that $<$ (and many other orderings) have.

So, you could say that there is a reason for defining things we way we do ... that reason being that we feel that that definition serves a useful purpose. We don't have a special word for numbers divisible by $17$ because it serves little purpose: unlike being divisible by $2$ (i.e. 'even'), which *is* a concept that can be fruitfully employed in many mathematical proofs and theorems, being divisible by $17$ is really not all that useful from the standpoint of gaining some interesting conceptual perspective about numbers or making proofs easier or more intuitive. But that is a far cry from saying that some definition is 'right' or wrong', let alone that we can prove that it is 'right' or 'wrong'.

So, the ultimate point remains: if you want to mathematically prove something, you *first* need to define things. And that's what they do here with the equivalence relationship.

Comment: Bram28 So literally mathematician spent half of their life to discover definition or axioms and spent another half of their life with such a great patience and passion to build theorems based on those definitions or axioms. Right?

Comment: @SabinaShrestha 'discover' is an interesting and probably not a bad word to use... yes, I suppose that you could say that sometimes mathematicians 'discover' an interesting or useful concept or insight and then codify that using a definition.  They can even be said to 'lay out' a domain. It is not as if they define stuff willy-nilly ... they come from somewhere .. from some consideration of some domain that is more or less imagined ... and definitions help to provide some kind of clarity or perspective to that as of yet ill-defined domain .. it provides a way to parse it and think about it.

Comment: But do they spend half their professional time on this?  ... the knee-jerk answer would be no: they spend far more time on proving theorems ... and I think that's true for many mathematicians  ... but maybe some of the more 'pure' or 'theoretical' mathematicians do spend a lot of time thinking of how they can characterize or frame some domain before proving anything about it. Indeed, sometimes mathematicians, after proving theorems, find that some of those theorems could be proven much more readily by changing or adding definitions. So they go back and forth.

Comment: Just one example of this: a 'prime number' used to be any number that is only divisible by 1 or itself. With that definition, 1 is a prime number ... and indeed, 1 used to be a prime number. But then mathematicians found it useful to exclude 1 from the prime numbers, and so they changed the definition: a prime number now must have exactly two different divisors: 1 and itself. So now 1 is no longer a prime number.